# Dispatcher wpf lança exceção ao chamar mais de uma action

Tags: c#, wpf, thread

Estou trabalhando em uma solução onde preciso fazer um encadeamento para execução de 3 métodos. Ou seja, preciso executar um, finalizar a execução, depois o outro e assim por diante.
Pra isso resolvi usar o Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. No momento que estou escrevendo o código não é lançada nenhuma exceção, mas quando vou executar é lançada uma exceção do tipo "A contagem dos parâmetros não coincide.".
Meu código é este aqui.

```
private void PesquisarComEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { AtualizaExecucao(); }, () => { PesquisarProcessos(); }, () => { FinalizarConsulta(); });
    }
```

O que estou fazendo errado para não funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

Com esse código, o método que está a ser invocado é este:

[`public System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke (Delegate method, params object[] args);`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke#system-windows-threading-dispatcher-begininvoke(system-delegate-system-object()))

Este método requere que, nest invocação, o `delegate` tenha 2 parâmetros que correspondam aos argumentos passados.

Penso que o pretendido é:

```
private void PesquisarComEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
           AtualizaExecucao();
           PesquisarProcessos();
           FinalizarConsulta();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer o encadeamento para execução dos 3 métodos, usei o parâmetro DispatcherPriority que oferece um nível de prioridade para a execução das actions.
Meu código ficou semelhante a isto aqui:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { PrimeiroMetodo() }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.DataBind);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { SegundoMetodo() }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { TerceiroMetodo() }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
```

Com isso consegui fazer com que os métodos fossem executados na ordem que eu precisava.

Para mais referencias sobre DispatcherPriority pode-se acessar este link: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority?view=windowsdesktop-6.0